# How do I find out how much an Android device output power is?

Tags: external-display

I have a SM-T510 in which I want to cast video to a Asus ZenScreen MB16AC using the [Android DisplayLink Presenter app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.displaylink.presenter&hl=en_US).

It's not working and I'm trying to figure out if the Galaxy is supplying enough power or if it's another issue.

I've plugged both devices into my laptop which has Ubuntu 18.04 installed and updated.

This command gives me the device id's when they are plugged in:

```
lsusb
```

I use this device id with these commands to get max power:

**ZenScreen:**

```
lsusb -v -d 17e9:4374
```

Power Result: MaxPower 500mA

**Galaxy:**

```
lsusb -v -d 04e8:6860
```

Power Result: MaxPower 64mA

The problem is I don't know if this is max input or max output or both. Or if this number is dependent upon some other influencing factor.

How do I get the max power out so I know if my ZenScreen can be powered by the Galaxy?

Comment: The commands you present cover AFAIK only the old wold before USB power delivery. Therefore they are totally irrelevant to you. At the moment it looks like power delivery profiles are automatically negotiated between the two devices and the cable in between but the result and the profiles are not accessible from outside. You may need need additional hardware to sniff the negotiation to get the data you want.

Comment: @Robert Do you know of any device that can test the input/ouput. It seems if they are doing this on their own that a tool should be able to query the device.